# The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value. PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a **table Sales**

```
Date         Order No.    Order qty   Product
Jan 1, 2016     O1          2           P1
Jan 2, 2016     O1          1           P2
Jan 1, 2016     O3          4           P1
Jan 2, 2016     O7          2           P5 And so on
```

I am trying to write a **DAX** for all orders in the table

```
TotalOrders = distinctcount(Sales[OrderNumber])
```

for e.g. here the number of distinct order IDs would be 3, order number 1, 3 and 7. So totalorders = 3

```
all orders = calculate([TotalOrders]/all(Sales))
```

I am getting an error in all orders measure.

> The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your measure

```
all orders = calculate([TotalOrders]/all(Sales))
```

You are passing a table 'Sales', not the count of the item. You need to change your DAX to

```
all orders = DIVIDE([TotalOrders], CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Sales), ALL(Sales))
```

If you data suit it you don't have to use ALL or ALLSELECTED, Just do a COUNTROWS(Sales)
You can create the measure which countrows. It is best practice to use the DIVIDE function rather than '/' as it handle errors such as divide by zero and nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/` with `,` (comma).

Query becomes:

```
all orders = calculate([TotalOrders],all(Sales))
```

It works perfectly now. So DAX is telling powerBI-hey, take totalorders from table sales.